# Как я могу реализовать постраничный вывод записей таблицы?

Tags: javascript, java, html

я столкнулся с задачей постраничного вывода записей таблицы. Как выглядит это сейчас: с сервлета передается **ArrayList** классов **Employer** (который содержит поля ID, Команда, Имя и т.д.), циклом ***c:forEach*** выводится конечная таблица в 1500 строк... На каждой строке есть кнопка **Delete**, и ссылка на редактирование по нажатию на ID конкретного человека. А также кнопка добавления и поля поиска по таблице(отправляется запрос в БД через сервлет)

**Вопрос:** Как и с помощью чего можно отрисовывать таблицу по выбраному кол-ву строк, ну т.е. как в интернет магазине: отобразить по 10(20 или 30) строк  а остальные раскидать по оставшимся страницам. Если можно то так чтобы капитально это все не переделывать, ибо времени на это уйдет многовато...

UPD1: Код страницы вывода:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ page pageEncoding="utf-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .CtrlF{
            color: #e03e07;
            position: absolute;
            right: 1130px
        }
    </style>
    <style>
        .searchLayer{
            position: absolute;
            right: 1000px
        }
    </style>

    <style>
        .DateLayer{
            position: absolute;
            right: 300px
        }
    </style>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Employers</title>
</head>
<body>
<style>
    .button {
        background-color: #cdcccc;
        color: black;
        padding: 3px 7px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        text-align: center;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: 16px;
        margin: 4px 2px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
</style>

<div class="searchLayer">
    <form action='<c:url value="/Search" />' class="search">
        <label>Поиск по</label>
        <select name="selectFrom" >
            <option value="ID">ID</option>
            <option value="kip">Команда проекта</option>
            <option value="dis">Дисциплина</option>
            <option value="role">Роль</option>
            <option value="employer">Сотрудник</option>
            <option value="workpl">План. Т/З</option>
            <option value="update">Изменил</option>
            <option value="add">Добавил</option>


        </select>
        <input type="search" name="search" placeholder="Поиск" class="input" />
        <input type="submit" value="search" />
    </form>
</div>
<div class="DateLayer">
    <form action='<c:url value="/Search" />'  class="search">
        <label>Поиск по дате</label>
        <select name="selectFrom" >
            <option value="start">План. старт</option>
            <option value="finish">План. финиш</option>
            <option value="DateAdd">Дата добавления</option>
            <option value="DateUp">Дата изменения</option>
        </select>
        <label>От:</label>
        <input type="date" name="d1" />
        <label>До:</label>
        <input type="date" name="d2" />
        <input type="submit" value="search" />
    </form>
</div>
<a class="button" href='<c:url value="/create" />'>Create new</a><br>
<a class="button" href='<c:url value="/" />'>Отменить сортировку</a>
<label class="CtrlF">Также чтобы найти запись нажмите "Ctrl" + F</label>
<table>
    <table border="1">

        <tr><th><a href = '<c:url value="/SortedID"/>'> ID</a> </th><th><a href = '<c:url value="/KipSorted"/>'> Команда проекта</a> </th><th><a href = '<c:url value="/DisSorted"/>'>Дисциплина</a></th><th><a href = '<c:url value="/RoleSorted"/>'> Роль</a></th><th><a href = '<c:url value="/NameSorted"/>'> Сотрудник</a> </th><th><a href = '<c:url value="/TZSorted"/>'> План. Т/З</a></th><th width="5%"><a href = '<c:url value="/StartSorted"/>'> План. старт</a></th><th><a href = '<c:url value="/FinSorted"/>'> План. финиш</a> </th><th><a href = '<c:url value="/CreateSorted"/>'>Дата добавления </a></th><th><a href = '<c:url value="/UpdateSorted"/>'> Дата изменения</a></th><th><a href = '<c:url value="/WhoUpdateSorted"/>'>Изменил</a></th><th><a href = '<c:url value="/WhoCreateSorted"/>'>Добавил</a></th><th></th></tr>
        <c:forEach var="employer" items="${employers}">
            <tr>
                <td><a href = '<c:url value="/edit?id=${employer.id}"/>'> ${employer.id}</a></td>
                <td>${employer.kip}</td>
                <td>${employer.dis}</td>
                <td>${employer.role}</td>
                <td>${employer.name}</td>
                <td>${employer.workpl}</td>
                <td>${employer.plst}</td>
                <td>${employer.plfin}</td>
                <td>${employer.datecr}</td>
                <td>${employer.dateup}</td>
                <td>${employer.whoup}</td>
                <td>${employer.whocr}</td>
                <td>

                    <form method="post" action='<c:url value="/delete" />'  style="display:inline;">
                        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="${employer.id}">
                        <input type="submit"  value="Delete">
                    </form>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Конкретно по jsp помочь не могу, но, надеюсь, будет полезно:

1. Вы можете добавить параметры `from` и `size` к запросу, и отдавать не все 1500 значений, а частями. Кнопки страниц с соответствующими параметрами придётся сгенерировать.
2. Попробуйте использовать [DataTables](https://www.datatables.net/) -- удобную библиотеку для пагинации таблиц.